# Jenkins does not attempt to update existing code. Clones every time

Tags: continuous-integration, jenkins, bitbucket

I'm attempting to get jenkins to build a project, but it seems to want to do a fresh clone everytime for some reason. I get this error:

```
none: ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/marc/repo/
which looks different than ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/marc/repo/
so falling back to fresh clone rather than incremental update
```

Is there something that would cause this? The two mentioned URLs are the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that with the debug option set to true (in the global jenkins settings for Mercurial) it will not update (but will clone), so this is a bug in the mercurial plugin for jenkins, but with a workaround that you can disable debug.

Answer (score 1):

Your build probably changes some files/directories in the original structure of your local copy. Jenkins detects it and restarts fresh to be clean.

regards

didier